# IBOutlet is nil in custom UIStoryboardSegue - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

So in Objective-C there was a little hack/work around to force load the `destinationViewController` in a custom `UIStoryboardSegue` by just calling `destinationViewController.view`.

However, in Swift the view property is impossible to call on its own and nor is it possible to test it for being nil in an if statement (as the property is not an Optional).

I’m using this way of force loading the view:

```
    if self.view.backgroundColor != nil {

    }
```

But it seems like (considering we’re on iOS 8 now) that this hack/work around should be unnecessary. Does anyone know of a more ‘legal’ way to get IBOutlets of a destination view controller in a custom segue?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to get the outlets of the destination controller in a custom segue?

Comment: To animate an outlet’d UIView

Comment: I'd be inclined to put that animation logic in the destination view controller. One view controller has no business messing around with the views of another view controller. And if the animation needed to be further tailored, I'd use custom transitions (with transition coordinators, animation controllers, etc.). Perhaps if you share the nature of your animation, we might be able to show you a completely different pattern that obviates the need for this hack.

Comment: The need of the transition is to animate a UIView from one location to another. The VC acts as a name editor of a UIDocument so similar to the iOS Pages app, the thumbnail animates to the destination VC